# Recurrence relation $ 2y_n = 11 y_{n-1} -20y_{n-2}+12y_{n-3}+2 $

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am really not an expert in mathematics. I'd like to solve the problem

$$
2y_n = 11 y_{n-1} -20y_{n-2}+12y_{n-3}+2 
$$

with $y_0 = \frac{9}{8}$, $y_1 = \frac{-5}{4}$ and $y_2 = \frac{-1}{2}$

Could you explain to me how to solve such problem?

Comment: keep plugging in the values and get the next one ...

Answer (score 3):

Let's use *symbolic differentiation* to get a homogeneous recurrence relation. Note that we have both $$2y_n-11y_{n-1}+20y_{n-2}-12y_{n-3}-2 = 0$$ and $$2y_{n-1}-11y_{n-2}+20y_{n-3}-12y_{n-4}-2 = 0$$ Subtracting the left-hand side of the second equation from the first gives us $$2y_n-13y_{n-1}+31y_{n-2}-32y_{n-3}+12y_{n-4} = 0$$ This has the characteristic equation $$2r^4-13r^3+31r^2-32r+12 = (r-2)^2(2r-3)(r-1) = 0$$ so our solution will have the form $$y_n = (c_1+c_2n)2^n+c_3(3/2)^n+c_4$$ At this point, you can plug in values for $y_n$ to get a linear system in the coefficients, which you can solve to find $$y_n = \left(-\frac{327}{8}+\frac{33n}{4}\right)2^n+44\cdot(3/2)^n-2$$

Comment: How did you factorize your characteristic equation?

Comment: I used the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) to check for possible rational roots (if none or only one of the roots had been rational, I would probably just have introduced constants $r_1$, $r_2$, etc. to represent the others). Fortunately, they were all rational. Of course, it's probably easier to do [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2r%5E4-13r%5E3%2B31r%5E2-32r%2B12).